# How to find unique value with id in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How to find unique value with id in JavaScript? right now I'm getting just value.

**I'm getting:-**

```
[
  "Care One",
  "Care Two"
]
```

**I need:-**

```
[
{
    "Source_ID": 1,
    "SourceName_CR": "Care One"
},
{
    "Source_ID": 2,
    "SourceName_CR": "Care Two"
}
```

]

**My code:-**

```js
const body = [
{
            Field_ID: 1,
            FieldName_CR: "First Name",
            Source_ID: 1,
            SourceName_CR: "Care One"
        },
        {
            Field_ID: 2,
            FieldName_CR: "Last Name",
            Source_ID: 1,
            SourceName_CR: "Care One"
        }, {
            Field_ID: 3,
            FieldName_CR: "Phone",
            Source_ID: 2,
            SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
        },
        {
            Field_ID: 4,
            FieldName_CR: "Email",
            Source_ID: 2,
            SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
        },  ];

console.log([...new Set(body.map(item => item.SourceName_CR))]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Set won't work here because you want to deduplicate objects - but objects can't be compared with each other that way. Doing just `.map(item => item.SourceName_CR)` doesn't make sense either because then you only get the string (eg `Care Two`) and not the whole object you want.

Group the source names by the source IDs to deduplicate, then turn the entries of the resulting object into the required structure.

```js
const body = [
{
    Field_ID: 1,
    FieldName_CR: "First Name",
    Source_ID: 1,
    SourceName_CR: "Care One"
},
{
    Field_ID: 2,
    FieldName_CR: "Last Name",
    Source_ID: 1,
    SourceName_CR: "Care One"
}, {
    Field_ID: 3,
    FieldName_CR: "Phone",
    Source_ID: 2,
    SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
},
{
    Field_ID: 4,
    FieldName_CR: "Email",
    Source_ID: 2,
    SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
},  ];
const namesBySourceID = Object.fromEntries(
  body.map(obj => [obj.Source_ID, obj.SourceName_CR])
);
const result = Object.entries(namesBySourceID)
  .map(([Source_ID, SourceName_CR]) => ({ Source_ID, SourceName_CR }));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would also work:

```js
const body = [ { Field_ID: 1, FieldName_CR: "First Name", Source_ID: 1, SourceName_CR: "Care One", }, { Field_ID: 2, FieldName_CR: "Last Name", Source_ID: 1, SourceName_CR: "Care One", }, { Field_ID: 3, FieldName_CR: "Phone", Source_ID: 2, SourceName_CR: "Care Two", }, { Field_ID: 4, FieldName_CR: "Email", Source_ID: 2, SourceName_CR: "Care Two", }, ];

const uniqueItems = [];

body.forEach(({Source_ID, SourceName_CR}) => {
    const found = uniqueItems.find(o => o.Source_ID === Source_ID);
    if(!found){
        uniqueItems.push({Source_ID, SourceName_CR});
    }
})

console.log(uniqueItems);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const body = [
{
            Field_ID: 1,
            FieldName_CR: "First Name",
            Source_ID: 1,
            SourceName_CR: "Care One"
        },
        {
            Field_ID: 2,
            FieldName_CR: "Last Name",
            Source_ID: 1,
            SourceName_CR: "Care One"
        }, {
            Field_ID: 3,
            FieldName_CR: "Phone",
            Source_ID: 2,
            SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
        },
        {
            Field_ID: 4,
            FieldName_CR: "Email",
            Source_ID: 2,
            SourceName_CR: "Care Two"
        },  ];
        
const key = 'SourceName_CR';

const uniqValues = [...new Map(body.map(item =>[item[key], item])).values()];

const onlyIDandNames=uniqValues.map((item)=>({Source_ID:item?.Source_ID,SourceName_CR:item?.SourceName_CR}))

console.log(uniqValues)
console.log(onlyIDandNames)
```